# Send GDoc / GSheet per script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

how I can send a file from GDrive with GMail per script. All examples which I can find are converting the file to a PDF before: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=en

Does anyone have a very simply example-script for me?

Greetings

Comment: "how I can send a file from GDrive with GMail per script." Could you be a bit more specific about the typer of file and whether you want to attach or include inline. Perhaps if you were to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I have a Test spreadsheet.  Here is how to send a copy of the file.  I test for type spreadsheet because I have many files named "Test".

```
function sendFile() {
  try {
    let files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title = "Test"');
    while( files.hasNext() ) {
      let file = files.next();
      file = file.makeCopy();
      if( file.getMimeType() === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" ) {
        GmailApp.sendEmail( 'myemail@gmail.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file. '+file.getUrl() );
      } 
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is nearly perfect. How I must create the script to add the file (link to GDrive) without the complete URL at the eMial-text.

Comment: You should see the link and a snapshot of the file in Gmail.  Click on either.

Comment: Yes it is correct but I do not want the link at the eMail only the snapshot.

Comment: So its both or none.